# Get unique domain names from a list of domains

Tags: python, regex

I have a list which can contain domains in a variety of ways:

```
[‘website.com’,
‘example.com’,
‘www.example.com’,
‘http://example.com’,
‘http://www.example.com’,
‘https://example.com’
]
```

How is it possible in regex or in Python to only get a list containing:

```
[‘website.com’,‘example.com’]
```

As you can see, all these examples of example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) have the same domain name, so I don’t need different variety of domains for my work.

Thanks

Comment: Look at `urllib.parse`. That will be quicker and more complete than cooking up your own regular expressions.

Comment: Are the two successive dots in `https://example..com` a typo?

Comment: https://example..com > yea its a typo

Comment: You should correct the question rather than just adding a comment (makes it easier for new viewers).

Comment: If you want to be correct, use a library to extract the hostname from the URLs, and now that you have only hostnames, to really find out the "registerable  domain" you need to use the Public Suffix List. You can't do it with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

urlparse from urllib.parse is ideal for this. For example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

URLS = ['website.com',
'example.com',
'www.example.com',
'http://example.com',
'http://www.example.com',
'https://example.com'
]

set_ = set()

for url in URLS:
    uri = urlparse(url)
    dom = uri.netloc or uri.path
    set_.add(dom if not dom.startswith('www.') else dom[4:])

print(list(set_))
```

**Output:**

```
['website.com', 'example.com']
```

Comment: OP asks: `How is it possible in regex or in Python to only get a list containing:
`[‘website.com’,‘example.com’]`.  I think example..com is a typo (should be one dot).

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to urlparse()
And thanks for answering